# How i set the value in created function before computed function initial

Tags: vue.js

I have a function in computed that needs to use the value from ajax in created function,because of vue lifecycle I can't get the value.

```js
created() {
  console.log('1');
  ajax.get('/xxx').then((res) => {
    console.log('2');
  });
},
computed: {
  tabs: function() {
    console.log('3');
    return [....];
  }
}
```

In console I get 1,3,2,3 but if i want to get the value i should get 1,2,3

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Write your template so that it can handle the state both before and after data is loaded. A common approach is to use [conditional rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Comment: I got it, thank you

Comment: sorry, when i use v-if ,and i got a lazy load  problem, "Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver'"What's wrong with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Vue component fail-safe.

In your case:

1. Use a flag for AJAX call completion state
2. Handle computed request with default value if AJAX call not successful
3. Handle computed request with compute if AJAX call was successful